# Google Maps API "Listings By"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google places API and it's working fine except it keeps displaying some kind of "Listings by" text. My map is only `500x400` so it shows up right into the center of the screen which looks really horrible.

I guess it's just some ad and it must be displayed ([according to docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResponses)). But is there anyway to change it's position?

Related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402028/google-places-search-api-and-listings-by-text) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034766/google-places-api-google-maps-listings-by-doesnt-get-reset-keeps-clutteri)

Note I'm already using one `PlacesService` object so it's not an issue of too many. It's just one line that goes out about 300px into the map.

Link to screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXwZR.png

```
createAmenitiesMarkers(type) {
    var _this = this;

    this.placesService = this.placesService || new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);

    this.placesService.nearbySearch({
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(
            this.address.location.coordinates[1],
            this.address.location.coordinates[0]
        ),
        radius: 1000,
        type: [type]
    }, function(results, status) {
        var i, ii;

        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (i = 0, ii = results.length; i < ii; i++) {
                _this.amenitiesMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: _this.map,
                    position: results[i].geometry.location,
                    title: results[i].name,
                    icon: {
                        url: 'http://mt.google.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/' + type + '_search_L_8x.png&scale=1'
                    }
                }));
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: show your code  ..

Comment: a screenshot would also be helpful

Comment: Added code sample and screenshot.

Comment: Some CSS of yours screwing it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to control this position using the API, but you can control positioning of other UI elements. If in your example you set:

```
zoomControlOptions: {
   position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
},
streetViewControlOptions: {
   position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
},
```

when initialising your map, the "Listing By" notice will appear just above the google copyright notice, which looks [way better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyUqw.png).